# Google VR View sideways on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, virtual-reality, google-vr

I'm testing the VR View player by Google through browserstack on iOS devices. When the device is upright the 360 image is sideways (though swiping left and right moves the image correctly still).

If I rotate the device so its landscape the VR View is then the right way up (as it doesn't rotate with the phone).

How do I make it upright when the phone is held upright?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I've fixed my own problem, seems like it was something to do with Browserstack. On an actual device it works perfectly.